# MongoDb: How to only update objects whose id are the same than new object's pushed in an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have an array of images in a mongo database that looks like this:

```js
pictures: [
  {id: "1", url: "url1/file/lala"},
  {id: "2", url: "url2/fila/lili"},
]
```

When a user wants to replace an image, the new image correctly replaces the former one in my cdn storage. I then receive a new url for this image. I need to either add the new object {id: "3", url: "url3/file/lolo" for example) to my pictures array if it doesn't exist in it, or to update/replace the objects whose id are the same than my new object(s).

How would you do that?

For the moment, I just have:

```js
router.post("/upload-images", upload.array("image"), async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.body;
  try {
    if (req.files) {
      let newProfilePicture = null;
      let otherPictures = [];
      req.files.forEach(({ path, originalname }) => {
            // handle upload here
            return originalname === "main"
              ? (newProfilePicture = res.secure_url)
              : otherPictures.push({ id: originalname, url: res.secure_url });
          }
        );
      });

      const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        userId,
        {
          profilePicture: newProfilePicture && newProfilePicture,
          // TODO ADD OTHER PICTURES
        },
        { new: true }
      );
      res.send("upload images success");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.send("upload images failed");
  }
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How to identify pictures is exists or not using id field? you are passing `otherPictures.push({ id: originalname,` originalname.

Comment: otherPictures is just the list of newImages I need to load in my db. Should I first fetch the user, perform a filter his images and then push otherPictures? Isn't there a more classy and performance wise technique?

Comment: you have already written this *I need to either add the new object {id: "3", url: "url3/file/lolo" for example) to my pictures array if it doesn't exist in it, or to update/replace the objects whose id are the same than my new object(s).* ........ how will you match existing images with id or its url? are you getting id parameters from request?

Comment: The id is the name of the file. It is based on the input position in my frontend. By doing this, I can easily replace the right file in my cdn storage. The id can be "main", "1", "2", etc.